# Android: When using ViewFlipper, can I start the in animation only after the out animation has ended?

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, viewflipper

I'm trying to create a 3d flip animation on a viewflipper.
By 3d flip I mean the following:
think of the current view as the front of a playing card, then turn it around on it's Y axis - this is a very common effect on iPhone and I'm trying to emulate it on android.
I have a pretty good implementation of a 3d flip but I need the out animation to only start after the in animation has ended.
Is that possible? I didn't really see many options in the android documentation.
Thanks,
e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a startOffset to the in animation that matches the duration of the out animation.

in xml it is

```
android:startOffset="milliseconds"
```

in code

```
animation.setStartOffset(milliseconds);
```

Set the startOffset to the same or greater value than the android:duration setting of the out animation.

Comment: yeah, that's what I ended up doing, however, i fear that if the first animation takes longer to perform for some reason, the animation as a whole will not work...

Comment: well, setting android:duration on the first animation should keep it limited to that time.